# Adding Queue to RabbitMQ Listener after Listener is started

Tags: spring, rabbitmq, amqp

I am using SimpleMessageContainerListener.
I have multiple queues required to listened with same Consumer. But Queues will be created dynamically after listener is configured and started. I cannot go with Topic because of application requirement.

I am using spring amqp. Here is my configuration:

```
<bean id="listenTest" class="org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer" 
p:connectionFactory-ref="connectionFactory" p:queueNames="testQueue1" 
p:messageListener-ref="messageListenerAdaptor" p:concurrentConsumers="2" p:prefetchCount="2" 
p:acknowledgeMode="MANUAL" p:channelTransacted="true"
/>
```

In above configuration consumer is listening to queue 'testQueue1'. I want to add more queues say 'testQueue2' and 'testQueue3' to be listened by same listener/consumer, after the beans are loaded.

Comment: I am using spring amqp. Here is my configuration: <bean id="listenTest" class="org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer" p:connectionFactory-ref="connectionFactory" p:queueNames="testQueue1" p:messageListener-ref="messageListenerAdaptor" p:concurrentConsumers="2" p:prefetchCount="2" p:acknowledgeMode="MANUAL" p:channelTransacted="true"/>

Comment: In above configuration consumer is listening to queue 'testQueue1'. I want to add more queues say 'testQueue2' and 'testQueue3' to be listened by same listener/consumer, after the beans are loaded.